# "Current" class on a singular page menu item with custom post types?

Tags: posts, menus, customization

I'm struggling to get a "current" class for the corresponding menu item when I'm on a singular (child) page of a custom post type. These are the arguments I used when registering the post type with register_post_type:

```
    array(
        'labels' => array(...),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        )
```

On the archive page everything is working fine and I do get the "current-menu-item" class for the current post types menu item. What can I do to make it work? I'm using wp_nav_menu(); to generate the menu.

Comment: Are you certain that [none of the numerous classes created automatically](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes) are sufficient?

Comment: WordPress adds a "current" class, by default. Specifically, [`.current-menu-item`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes). For hierarchical menu items, WordPress also outputs `.current-{post_type}-parent` and `.current-{post_type}-ancestor`. Can you provide a live link to the output?

Comment: @s_ha_dum @Chip Bennet None of the automatically created classes are sufficient. The classes of the corresponding menu item are `menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-92` when I'm on a singular page. Unfortunately I don't have a live link right now.

Comment: What are the classes on the parent items? I'd like to see the menu output as well.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Maybe [this](http://pastebin.com/WEAMHpfk) clarifies?

Comment: Does your theme use a custom Walker? I just did a quick test with book post type [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and there is a `current-menu-item` class. Your markup look very minimal.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Not that I'm aware of, so probably no. Did you also get the `.current-book-ancestor` in your test? Because I do get the `current-menu-item` class as per my pastebin code. How did you add the post type to the menu?

Comment: I get `menu-item-object-book` and `current-menu-item` for the item itself, and `current-menu-ancestor` and `current-menu-parent` for the parent menu item. Like I said, your markup looks truncated to me.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Ok, any idea what might cause that?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the markup of your menu does not seems to generating all of the classes I'd expect to see, I'll guess at the problem.

1. Your theme is using a [custom Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function)
2. Or something-- theme or plugin-- has added a [filter to (probably)
   `wp_nav_menu_css`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Adding_Conditional_Classes_to_Menu_Items).
3. Though there are [other filters that could be used](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L0).

To fix it, or try to, make sure your theme does not include a `walker` argument when it calls `wp_nav_menu` and search your theme and plugins for `wp_nav_menu_css` and other [relevant filters](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L0).

If it is a walker you can remove that walker argument, though it may effect other theme functionality. If it is a filter it can be removed with [`remove_filter()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after going every file of my theme through and disabling all plugins, I still haven't found a solution :( Could something be wrong with how I register the post type?